# how to change the color of a line after it was plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib

Well a simple question that I did not found the answer to..

I want to change the color of a line that I already plotted

ipython -pylab

```
figure()
a = plot([1,2,3],[2,2,3],'r')

a.Change_Color('b')
```

Comment: Try `a.set_color('red')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
a[0].set_color('blue')
```

and perhaps you have to update the plot with `show()` or `draw()`.